# NT BATCH - String Display issues

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing an NT batch script (I can't install powershell, or any other more advanced scripting language on the machine this needs to run on).

I need to reboot the server on a schedule (and again, the machine this needs to run on doesn't have task scheduler in the build).

So I'm doing date manipulation to determine how many seconds timeout to pass to shutdown.exe when this runs as a startup script.

Consider the following:

```
SET RAt = "04:15"
SET RHour = %RAt:~0,2%
SET RMin = %RAt:~3,2%
```

and

```
Echo Server will reboot in %Days2Reboot% Days (%Secs2Reboot% seconds), on %GDate% at approximately %RHour:~0,2%:%RMin%
```

The value of `RAt` isn't displayed, and if I change the `echo` statement to instead display `%RHour%:%RMin%` the value of RHour is 4, not 04 - how do I either fix the display of the HH:MM format string value, or force display of a number to a certain number of digits?

Comment: Don't use spaces in your `SET` commands.

Comment: Which Windows Server version is this for?

Comment: I should have note that you are assigning quotes to your variable.  Best Practice is to not assign quotes to your variables but do use them to surround the set command to protect special characters and trailing spaces. `SET "RAt=04:15"`

Comment: @Squashman frustratingly simple! You can tell I’m happier in powershell etc! Thank you - if you make this an answer I’ll mark it as such

Comment: @Compo developing on a Win7 Enterprise machine but it will be running on a WinXP Embedded 2002 SP2 - yes really!

Comment: @Squashman yeah, that was a misguided attempt to solve the display issues. Removed now and noted for future :-)

Comment: Graham, what's wrong with my answer, instead of asking for somebody else to do so.

Comment: @Compo I hadn’t got to it yet, reading in the order posted. However not only was Squashman first to respond, they also explicitly stated where I was going wrong eg extraneous spaces matter and should be removed

Comment: Graham, my answer specifically tells you the recommended syntax, it is the same thing.

Comment: @Compo I might not have gleaned from your answer that spaces were my issue - or I might have found they didn’t matter if I quoted the name=value pair (I don’t know if that is indeed the case, haven’t tried it, but I have removed the spaces as per Squashmans’ comment, which did resolve my issue)

Comment: Graham, there's no prizes for pedantry, the recommended syntax doesn't show any spaces does it? If you use the recommended syntax, your problem would be solved, wouldn't it? Do you want me to add a note to the answer specifically mentioning the spaces, even though the recommended syntax, has already dealt with it?

Comment: @Compo not at all, I’m giving the person who solved my problem first the chance for the credit. I think that’s only fair. If Squashman doesn’t post their comment up as an answer I will gladly mark your post as the answer.

Comment: @Compo having seen your update - it is the most complete answer. Let it sit for a bit then it will likely be marked as the answer - was simply trying to fair, even if it doesn’t seem that way

Comment: Graham, it's the only answer! If your not happy with it then don't mark it as accepted, I'm certainly not in desperate need of your acceptance, _despite having voluntarily spent a small portion of my day helping you!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graham, your code currently does not use the recommended syntax, and as such is your problem.

If you `SET RAt = "04:15"` you are setting a variable named <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> to a value of  <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.

When you `Set` a variable, it is recommended to not include doublequotes as part of the value, but to do so at the time you actually use it, i.e. `"%VariableName%"`. To protect certain characters in the VariableValue, or prevent hidden whitespace being appended to the value, surrounding the variable pair with doublequotes is recommended

The recommended syntax for the `Set` command is therefore:

```bat
Set "VariableName=VariableValue"
```

I'd suggest that you consider the following type of modification based on the above advice:

```bat
SET "RAt=04:15"
SET "RHour=%RAt:~,2%" % or ~0,2 % % or ~-5,2 %
SET "RMin=%RAt:~-2%" % or ~3,2 %
```

Of course if the content of the variable is really already doublequoted:

```bat
SET "RHour=%RAt:~1,2%" % or ~-6,2 %
SET "RMin=%RAt:~-3,2%" % or ~4,2 %
```

*The strings at the end of the set lines between the percent characters are alternatives as commentary, they can be removed*